# How to do MCDC for conditions that depend on each other?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, automated-tests, testcase, mc-dc

I run into a problem when doing [MCDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_condition/decision_coverage) for the expression below:

```
if( 
(t_Active_b == FALSE)
&& 
(
   (t_State_ub != HOLD) && 
   (t_State_ub != RELEASE) &&
   (t_State_ub != CAPTURE) 
)
||
t_signal_ub == FAILED
)
```

From the expression, I have 5 conditions in total

[ A && (B && C && D) || E ]

As MCDC requires: "a change in one condition results a change in output",

which means if A changes (t_Active_b has the value TRUE and then FALSE) and other conditions have to keep its state then the output changes (from TRUE to FALSE)

How can I design the test cases for condition B, C, and D?

By the way, do you know any commercial or free tool that can generate MCDC test cases?

Answer (score 2):

The original definition of MCDC (Modified Condition Decision Coverage) did not consider several cases. One of them is a reason for your problem. You have "coupled conditions". That means, the same condition is used more than once. There are strong and weak coupled conditions. As an example: In the boolean expression:
"ab+ac" the variable "a" is existing in 2 product terms. As per the original definition, it is not possible to find a test pair that would fulfill unique cause MCDC.

This lead to many problems and basically to a new definition for 3 forms of MCDC

1. Unique Cause (as per the original definition)
2. Unique Cause + Masking
3. Masking

What is Masking?

Masking takes the property of the boolean Annihilator into account. Meaning "A and FALSE" --> FALSE      and    "A or TRUE" --> TRUE.

So, if a boolean expression is evaluated and it is clear already and early that a subterm  cannot contribute to a result, then there is no need to evaluate that. The subterm is masked. It does not matter.

The same mechanism is, by the way, also used for boolean short cut evaluation.

With that relaxation you can find more test pairs for an influencing variable. NASA and FAA will accept also these additional forms of MCDC.

If we use Masking for the influencing variable, then we call the test-pair-MCDC-property "Unique Cause + Masking". If we allow all masked variables to change, then we call test-pair-MCDC-property "Masking".

For the above example "ab+ac" you can find the following test pairs:

```
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  1,  5   Unique Cause + Masking
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  2,  6   Unique Cause + Masking
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  3,  5   Masking
Influencing Condition: 'a'  Pair:  3,  6   Masking
Influencing Condition: 'b'  Pair:  4,  6   Unique Cause
Influencing Condition: 'c'  Pair:  4,  5   Unique Cause
```

(5 is e.g. the decimal equivalent of the setting of variable abc, in this case 101).

Applying the set cover problem would lead to 3 possible test sets

-------- Coverage set   1    ----------------------------------------------------

```
Test Pair for Condition 'a':    1   5   (Unique Cause + Masking)
Test Pair for Condition 'b':    4   6   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'c':    4   5   (Unique Cause)
```

Resulting Test Vector:  1 4 5 6

-------- Coverage set   2    ----------------------------------------------------

```
Test Pair for Condition 'a':    2   6   (Unique Cause + Masking)
Test Pair for Condition 'b':    4   6   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'c':    4   5   (Unique Cause)
```

Resulting Test Vector:  2 4 5 6

-------- Coverage set   3    ----------------------------------------------------

```
Test Pair for Condition 'a':    1   5   (Unique Cause + Masking)
Test Pair for Condition 'b':    4   6   (Unique Cause)
Test Pair for Condition 'c':    4   5   (Unique Cause)
```

Resulting Test Vector:  1 4 5 6

And a final result of:

---

Testvector: Recommended Result: 1 4 5 6

```
1:  a=0  b=0  c=1    (0)
4:  a=1  b=0  c=0    (0)
5:  a=1  b=0  c=1    (1)
6:  a=1  b=1  c=0    (1)
```

Please note:

It is important to understand that you need to look on boolean expressions with a WhiteBox view. MCDC is a structural coverage metrick and hence you need to know the source code. Anyway. In a lot of videos and explanations people start explaining MCDC from a truth table (BlackBox). This will never work for masking or for more complex expressions. In the above example you would not find the 3 and 5 to be a valid MCDC test pair. This can be found only with a WhiteBox approach.

I deeply anaylzed the problem and published a tool to see test cases

GitHub:  [MCDC](https://github.com/Armin-Montigny/MCDC)

Please contact me, if you need support with that.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you can consider ( B, C , D) as a big condition named for example BC and do MCDC for the expression (A && BC || E)

For Another approach, you can take a look at this article

https://www.digitalobjectivo.com/mcdc-test-cases-generator/

Comment: Indeed, this makes sense. You then do need a 4th state like RUNNING in my answer, to be able to make your BigCondition false.

Comment: The link is to digitalobjectivo is broken :-(

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that conditions B/C/D are not independent: If you make one of them false, the other two are automatically true.

So if you want to stick to Boolean MC/DC, you need a 'fourth' case, which would make all of B/C/D true, for example a fourth state `t_State_ub == RUNNING`.

The test cases then would become:

- T1: (A,B,C,D,!E)  -> T (inactive, RUNNING, not failed)
- T2: (A,!B,C,D,!E) -> F (inactive,    HOLD, not failed)
- T3: (A,B,!C,D,!E) -> F (inactive, RELEASE, not failed)
- T4: (A,B,C,!D,!E) -> F (inactive, CAPTURE, not failed)
- T5: (!A,B,C,D,!E) -> F (ACTIVE,   RUNNING, not failed)
- T6: (!A,B,C,D,E)  -> T (ACTIVE,   RUNNING, FAILED)

T2-T5 all differ with T1 in one condition and in the outcome, and T6 differs with T5 in one condition and in the outcome, thus meeting the MC/DC requirements.

Note that conditions BCD are effectively `!(ub == HOLD || ub == RELEASE || ub == CAPTURE)`. If there is no fourth state like `RUNNING`, this condition is unnecessary and can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, B/C/D are coupling, but don't mean that test cases can't be generated. It dedenpends on the definition of `t_State_ub` .

If `t_State_ub`  has only 3 kinds of status like `HOLD`,`RELEASE` and `CAPTURE`, then you can't get test cases for B/C/D conditions compliant to the original mc/dc principle(i.e. Unique Cause MC/DC).

However, it seems `t_State_ub`  has other status, I guess. so it's working to generate mcdc cases.

If `t_State_ub`  has not other status, `(t_State_ub != HOLD) && (t_State_ub != RELEASE) && (t_State_ub != CAPTURE)` can never be TRUE, so  the logic is redundent.